# How can I validate user input (characters and number) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

From [this example](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-validate-email-address-regex/)
I tried to validate user input when a button was clicked.

```
$("#check_data").click(function () {
    var $userInput = $('#user_input'); //from HTML input box id="user_input"
    var pattern = " /*My user input always be like "AB1234567"*/ ";
    if ($userInput.val() == '' || !pattern.test($userInput.val())) {
        alert('Please enter a valid code.');
        return false;
    }
});
```

My user input input always be like "AB1234567" with this exact same characters but different 7 digits number.
I'm new to Javascript and Jquery, if you have any better way to validate user input, please suggest it.

Thank you.

Comment: So the value is in the pattern of AB1234567, but it's not the exact value?  Sounds like you need to use regular expressions.

Comment: try this pattern 
^AB[0-9]{7}?

Comment: the pattern you need: [a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7} suppose to be any letter max 2 any number max 7

Answer (score 1):

You can use below regex Expression to check

```
/[A-Za-z0-9]/g
```

Your code could be like this

```
    var _pattern=/[A-Za-z0-9]/g
    if($userInput.val().match(_pattern))
    {
        //your code goes here..
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below pattern to check

```
/^AB\d{7}$/
```

You can change code to

```
var pattern = '/^AB\d{7}$/';
  if ($userInput.val() == '' || !pattern.test($userInput.val()))
  {
     alert('Please enter a valid code.');
     return false;
  }
```

`\d{7}` matches 7 digits in the range [0-9]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below code for this:

```
if ($userInput.val().match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g))
{
    // it is a valid value.

} else {
    // show error here
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$("#check_data").click(function(){
  var $userInput = $('#user_input').val();
  var pattern = /^AB[0-9]{7}?/g;
  if(!$userInput.match(pattern)){
      alert('Please enter a valid code.');
      return false;
  }
});
```